# change style of button on focus of input box

Tags: html, css

Problem:
I want to change style of button on focus of input element.

Here is the template code:

```
<input type="text"></input>
  <span>
    <button class="search">Poor Me!</button>
  </span>
```

Here is the css code:

```
.search-form input:focus{
  border: 1px solid #009BC6;
  outline: none;
}

.search-form input:focus + .search{
  background-color: #009BC6;
  outline: none;
}
```

Expected Output:
On focus of input box
1. Apply border of 1x width to input box
2. Change background color of button

Actual Output:
1. Border is applied to input box
2. No changes in background color of button

http://jsfiddle.net/6Y8GL/7/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

demo -http://jsfiddle.net/6Y8GL/8/

```
input:focus ~ span #btnClick {
 background: red;
}
```

css cant find the `#btnclick` because it is not the sibling of the `input` you should be more specific, target the `span` and then `#btnClick`

```css
input:focus {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
input:focus ~ span #btnClick {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text"></input>
<span>
    <button id="btnClick">Click Me!</button>
</span>
```

Comment: I should update my knowledge of css3. Thanks it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `span` around your button. The symbol `+` called next immediate sibling. According to your markup button is not next immediate sibling element.

```
<input type="text"></input>
<button class="search">Poor Me!</button>
```

Comment: I should have been more specific about code. I am using bootstrap so that span is required.

Answer (score 0):

Try CSS:

```
input + span button {
    background :blue;
}
input:focus + span button {
    background :red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.search-form input:focus + .search` , use `input:focus ~ span > #btnClick`

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Y8GL/9/)

Working Demo:

```css
input:focus{
    border: 2px solid green;
}

input:focus ~ span > #btnClick{
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text"></input>
<span>
    <button id="btnClick">Click Me!</button>
</span>
```